# Mongoose delete document field instead of whole document

Tags: node.js, mongoose

**Instead of deleting the otp attribute the Query is deleting whole document**

**Schema. I want to delete otp after verified**

```
const LoginSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    password:String,
    verified: Boolean,
    otp:Number
});

const Model = mongoose.model("Users", LoginSchema);
```

**Query in Post Request**

```
 app.post("/verify/:id", async(req, res) => {

var User = await Model.findOne({ _id: req.params.id, otp:req.body.otp });

Model.deleteOne({ otp: User.otp }, (err, res) => {
                    if (err) console.log(err)
                    else console.log("succesful");
                })
})
```

Comment: this is actually very short code where the problem lies. i have skipped every irrelevent stuff

Comment: Have a look at https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html#overwriting

Comment: What's the reason behind deleting the field `otp` ? Isn't it enough, for example, to just set it to `null` or `false` ?

Comment: I was actually updating it will Null.
But then I realized I may need this concept in the future but with different objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That because you deleting a document when you using '*deleteOne*'. You need to `$unset` the otp attribute.

Try this one:

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate({ otp: User.otp }, {$unset: {otp: 1 }},(err, res) => {
                    if (err) console.log(err)
                    else console.log("succesful");
                })
})
```

Comment: what does it mean by  `{otp : 1 }`

Comment: The value as no impact, you can read more:  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/#mongodb-update-up.-unset